# ExtJS include View in cmd build

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I use ExtJS 5. I use Sencha Architect.

I have 2 views: View1 (alias: widget.view1) and View2 (alias widget.view2). Those views are declared in views folder but are not linked in application. One of them is created at runtime and added to container in beforerender:

```
component.add({xtype: 'view' + type});
```

where `type` variable is calculated earlier.

I build app with

```
sencha app build testing
```

and in created JS file there is no View1 neither View2 included. Also there is no appropriate ViewController neither ViewModel.

Then I've added subsections in `app.json` file in section `js`:

```
  {
     "path": "app/view/View1.js",
     "x-compile": true,
     "includeInBundle": true
  },
  {
     "path": "app/view/View1ViewController.js",
     "x-compile": true,
     "includeInBundle": true
  },
  {
     "path": "app/view/View1ViewModel.js",
     "x-compile": true,
     "includeInBundle": true
  },
```

and rebuild app. Now the View1 class is available in compiled JS and also during runtime.

Question: how can I make SA to modify `app.json` file? There is a file `app.json.meta` created by SA (I guess). The content of both files is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution.
I need to add `AppName.view.View1` and `AppName.view.View2` to `requires` table of container where I need to add views.